# Problem with Moodle Login using Web Services

Tags: javascript, web-services, authentication, moodle

Hello to the whole community. :)

I am currently working on integrating moodle for an e-learning platform. I have implemented most of the functionalities using web services (Javascript Client). But, unfortunately, I find that the web authentication service does not exist.

I said to myself, for authentication at the level of my system without redirecting the user to moodle from the information in the moodle database, I retrieve the password from the login and I test with the data entered by the user but the concern is that the core_user_get_users and core_user_get_users_by_fields functions do not send me the password (encrypted) but just the other information.

Need your help !!

Comment: If you update your question with some example code, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

core_user_get_users and core_user_get_users_by_fields are, quite correctly, incapable of sending the user's password, because Moodle itself doesn't know what the user's passwords are.

Moodle only stores a one-way hash of the user's passwords - each time a user logs in, the hash of the password they entered is compared with that in the database and the user is allowed in, if they match. By design, it is very difficult (and time consuming) to start with the hashed password in the Moodle database and figure out the user's password.

If you need a mechanism for logging a user in to Moodle from your system, without them having to enter a password, then you should consider using a Moodle authentication plugin that supports Single Sign On - the standard Moodle authentication plugins are listed at: https://docs.moodle.org/en/Authentication, but you may find that there is a 3rd-party authentication plugin that helps you at: https://moodle.org/plugins/?q=type:auth (https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2 is often a good place to start).